# how to send photo and other data to server by using json

Tags: android, json, web-services, service, android-asynctask

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
temp_photo3.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,stream);
byteArrays3 = stream.toByteArray();
byte[] photo = byteArrays3 ;
String str_photo="";
str_photo= Base64.encodeToString(photo, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

photo encoded in base 64 format,and sending in bytearray format to server,It works by using soap action,but not working in json.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
         

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://xyz.jtsncsfg.com/Service.asmx/Insert_Photo_Json");

        List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("log_ID", getLogID+""));
        list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Photo", str_photo));
        list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat",  Lat+""));
        list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longi",  Longi+""));
        list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("remark",get_remark));
        list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", Long.toString(getUserID)));
         

         
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
         
        
        String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()).toString();      // here i m getting responce 
                        
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonResult);

        String str_root  = object.getString("ID");

        
        if(str_root.equals("1"))                 
        {
            problm1 = 1;                    
        }
        else if(str_root.equals("0"))
        {
            problem2 = 2;
        }
        else if(str_root.equals("Not Saved.."))
        {
            problem3 = 3;
        }
     
        
        
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        problem3 = 3;
    }                         
    return null;

}
```

It gives following error

> Cannot convert 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
>
> ... to System.Byte.Parameter name: type ---> Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: yes i have used it,but still giving error

Comment: use use base64.com website. you can compare your base64 encoded data and there data. this will help

Comment: http://www.base64-image.de/step-1.php  This will help you to get the encoded image and compare your base64 image encoded data.. and check... both of them has to be the same.

Comment: `t gives following error`. Where? On which statement? On server or client? You are nowhere using the base64 encoded string `str_photo`. And you are not using json to send the foto. So please adapt your text or code.

Comment: `photo encoded in base 64 format,and sending in bytearray format `. Well that is nonsense. You have the foto base64 encoded to a String.

Comment: i have used base 64 input,and sending base 64 format also,please check once again

Comment: where you getting following error on Server or client side?

Comment: we are getting this error from http response